# What is an example of state pattern in Core Java/JSF/Servlets?

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, design-patterns, state-pattern

I just learnt about the State pattern . I would like to know where in core Java / JSF/Servlets  code s can I see this pattern being implemented ? I want to see how the state transition is implemented and who plays the role of `states` and who plays the role of `context` there ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns/2707195#2707195

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JSF it can be lifecycle processing. `Phase` is a state with concrete states: `ApplyRequestValuesPhase`, `InvokeApplicationPhase`, `ProcessValidationsPhase`, `RenderResponsePhase`, `RestoreViewPhase`, `UpdateModelValuesPhase`. Context would be `Lifecycle`.

NOTE: This example is from Mojarra implementation of JSF.

Comment: Note that the mentioned `Phase` implementations are Mojarra (`com.sun.faces.*`) specific. MyFaces (`org.apache.myfaces.*`) gave them different names.